# Material likely to contain asbestos?

Tags: asbestos

[image]
In basement, nailed into ceiling joists. Could be old tile / ceiling material?

Comment: Old ceiling tile could contain asbestos. From the tight grain of the wood it looks like your home is older than 70's so I would have it tested.

Answer (score 1):

It could be but you won't know for sure unless it's tested. You can have a professional company come in or you can get a home test kit that you mail in after taking a sample. The 2nd option is cheapest.